# Property call in for-loop design issue

Tags: .net, for-loop, properties, c++-cli

I've had a discussion with collegues this morning concerning for-loop-optimization. It was pretty much the situation as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116188/c-for-loop-optimization-question), however the code was C++/CLI and the method called a property *from a different assembly*. I'm aware that in this case the compiler can't optimize the loop by inlining the function. However, the subject was image processing and the properties called were width and height of an image, i.e.:

```
for (unsigned int y = 0; y < image.Height; ++y) {
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < image.Width; ++x) {
        // Do something with pixel x,y
    }
}
```

For a 5M grayscale image, that loop took about 450 ms, whereas when saving width and height to local variables before executing the loop, the time consumption was about 10 ms! (These numbers are only given to show the magnitude of the difference.)

Of course, we are heading for the local variable solution now, but I wonder whether the naive for-loop given above is actually bad design? When writing such code, I wouldn't expect any real compiler optimization, but calls to *trivial* properties like width and height of an image I'd expect to return their value way quicker. So isn't the whole problem due to bad design of the image library authors? When using trivial properties, shouldn't I prever readability?

Comment: Did you measure this without the debugger attached and with a release build?

Comment: *"shouldn't I prever readability?"* - Well, I'm not convinced that saving two properties to local variables first reduces readability, but I would like to know your compiler settings and environment.

Comment: [...when the runtime is run in debugging mode, the JIT compiler will not perform certain optimizations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384548(v=vs.110).aspx), so if you're measuring in debug mode, don't assume inlining will happen.

Comment: Of course it was run in release mode.

Comment: And yes, two locals won't affect readability, but I'm wondering if properties like these shouldn't be *designed* to be usable in a loop.

Comment: You didn't answer @Steven's question; was the debugger attached? That may suppress JIT optimizations on module load.  Specifically, make sure this option is disabled (or don't attach the debugger): Tools + Options, Debugging, General, Supress JIT optimization on module load

Comment: I ask because you made this statement: *"I'm aware that in this case the compiler can't optimize the loop by inlining the function"* - The C# *compiler* never inlines *anything*; the JIT'er does.  Those properties can (perhaps) be inlined.

Comment: I just asked the programmer who did it and found out that the build was indeed Release, but started from VisualStudio, i.e. with Debugger attached. However, could the *JIT* inline these properties if they are from a third-party assembly? It's not a `System.Drawing.Image`.

Comment: @Matz The JIT does a pretty good job of inlining if the debugger hasn't disabled it, so you should definitely test it without the debugger attached.

Answer (score 0):

I agree the design decision is kind of odd, at least on the surface of things. Many of the underlying datatypes in `System.Drawing` map to native GDI(?) types, which will slow simple things down.

Most likely though, it will speed things up once you actually want to draw the image to the screen since there's no extra mapping to native types when actually drawing the image.

For example, the essentials of `Image.Height`;

```
public int Height {
    get { 
        int height;
        int status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipGetImageHeight(new HandleRef(this, nativeImage), out height); 

        if (status != SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.Ok) 
            throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(status);

        return height;
    } 
}
```

Inlining this method won't necessarily improve performance, the bulk of the time is most likely spent in the native call fetching the actual height, which is why fetching `Height` once and not in a loop will (in this case by design) make things much faster.

Comment: The OP never said that `image` was a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.  Not a ridiculous assumption though.

Comment: @EdS. Actually that was `Image.Height`, `Bitmap` was a typo.

Comment: It's a third-party library, not from `System.Drawing`. However, even in that case, wouldn't you expect the wrapper to cache a value like `height` in order to execute the property query faster?

Comment: @Matz I agree 100% that doing work in the properties that can be avoided isn't the best performance decision for your loop's purposes, however it may simplify other code paths that would be harder to work around. Hard to discuss third party code though, especially without even knowing what code you're talking about :)